# How smooth/rough is a liquid surface?

Tags: optics, fluid-statics

Surface tension makes liquid surfaces smooth, but how smooth? How rough?

This question has an Experimental version and a Theoretical version:

> **E :** Optics manufacturers quote specs like $1/4$ or $1/8$ wavelength ($100-400$ nm), which seems to be RMS surface deviation. How does a calm liquid surface compare? How would one measure the liquid roughness?
>
> **T :** Is there a good model to explain liquid surface roughness? What are the determining factors? Atomic diameter? Temperature? Density? Pressure applied to the interface?

Thanks!

Comment: Rotating liquid mirrors are worthwhile in some cases to get very good optical performance.

Comment: Can that be quantified and explained, though?

Comment: https://www.americanscientist.org/article/liquid-mirror-telescopes gives a high level overview.

Comment: Thanks! Great article, and very fun to read. It suggests that the mirrors are smooth enough to achieve diffraction limited results, which gives an upper bound. There is still no value or model yet, but I might look into some of the papers cited in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a similar thing. First of all, roughness is not an absolute unit as it depends on the object to be analyzed (the smooth or rough one) and the object that intercalates on that surface. In a macro and super-simple approach we could use friction as a measure of roughness. Moving to a medium scale we can thing on a surface of a material with peaks and valleys, in that case you can measure the frequencie and the absolute depth of those peaks (statistics). But I think that you want something even more little, that is my field.
In that case usually depends on what do you want to intercalate in that surface, for different elements or molecules you can assume a surface as smooth as it can not be adsorbed easily in the surface. But lets assume you have a flat interphase for the liquid (if not you can use curvature as a measure of the roughness) and you just want to have a physical measure of the roughness (avoiding chemistry details), in this case what you can use as a measure of roughness is to simulate the liquid surface with molecular dynamics and use any kind of distribution function that adjust to the geometry (example a sphere-> radial distribution function centered on the axis origin). A "smooth" surface will have a sharp distribution on the surface, meanwhile a "rough" surface will have a smoothest distribution.

But remember, roughness is a relative unit so i recommend you to use the sharpness distribution (at some temperature) that you find as the smoothest (the zero) and the compare with highest temperatures. If you change the particles involved in the liquid, and the have different size i recommend you to normalize in some way using the radius or the mean radii of the elements in the surface.